# Create a multi-select drop down list in Excel VBA without duplicates for multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I have the following code which works to an extent with data validation on a predefined list on aa separate sheet. The issue I am having is that the drop down list lets me select an item more than once. However, I want to be able to select an Item only once.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngDV As Range
    Dim oldVal As String
    Dim newVal As String

If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)

On Error GoTo exitHandler


    If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler
    If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then

    'do nothing
  Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newVal = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    oldVal = Target.Value

    Target.Value = newVal

    If oldVal = "" Then

    'do nothing
    
    Else
    If newVal = "" Then
    
    'do nothing
    
    Else
    Target.Value = oldVal _
      & ", " & newVal
    
   End If
 End If
End If

exitHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the drop-down cells in a contiguous column range? Cells is referring to all worksheet cells, that's a lot of cells.

Comment: Yes - Is that the issue?

Comment: No, that's not the issue. I need the first row and the column of the drop-down cells to use `Application.Match` (which wouldn't work if the cells were scattered around) to compare the target values with the previous values.

Comment: Is this related to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70593083/) ?

Comment: @VBasic2008, The first row and column of the drop-down cell is D4. My aim for this exercise is to populate an entire sheet through the use of drop down. So the range of cells where I have a data validation/ drop-down really ranges from D4 to Y150. Is this going to be an issue?

Comment: That's 22 columns. I thought it was one. Can you explain in more detail, possibly using a practical example, what shouldn't be repeated and the concatenating of old and new.

Comment: Ok. Take sheet 1 and Sheet 2. Sheet 1 contains  22 columns and about 100 rows including a header. Sheet 2, let's call this "Options" also contains 22 columns matching the headers of sheet 1 with a list of options for each columns that will be used to populate sheet 1 through a data validation rule.

Comment: Back to sheet 1. First column header is called "Colours". A list of colours is also available as options in sheet 2 say "Green, Blue, Yellow, Red, Orange" in the first Column. 

From Row A2 in sheet 1, I want a drop down that selects say only "Green, Red, Orange" with no duplicates and subsequently repeat the procedure for the remaining 21 columns (With different headers and options of course).

Comment: Maybe look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35044090/478884

Comment: @Tim Willimas, Thank you. Your example works.. to an extent. When  I clear a cell, I can no longer select any options from my drop down list. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: How are you clearing the cell, and what exactly happens when you try to make a selection after clearing the cell?  There's no list, or there's a list but you can't select from it?